# PySpark schema not recognised

Tags: python, pyspark

i'm attempting to convert a csv file using this schema :

```
sch = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("words", ArrayType((StringType())), True)
])

dataFile = 'mycsv.csv'

df = sqlContext.read.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").schema(sch).option("delimiter", format(",")).option("charset", "UTF-8").load(dataFile, format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema='false')
```

mycsv.csv contains :

```
id , words
a , test here
```

I expect df to contain `[Row(id='a', words=['test' , 'here'])]`

but instead its an empty array as `df.collect()` returns `[]`

Is my schema defined correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, clearly your `words` column isnt of type `Array` its of type StringType() only. and since you have DROPMALFORMED enabled, its droping the records because its not matching Array schema. Try schema like below and it should work fine -

```
sch = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("words", StringType(), True)
])
```

edit : if you really really want 2nd column as Array/List of words , do this -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
df.select(df.id,split(df.words," ").alias('words')).show()
```

this outputs :

```
+---+--------------+
| id|         words|
+---+--------------+
| a |[, test, here]|
+---+--------------+
```